# Exchange 2010 Losing Customized Views in Outlook Clients

Tags: exchange, outlook

Has anyone seen a case where Exchange 2010 resets end-user custom views back to the defaults? I have a user who has tricked out their profile with (server-side) custom views, mostly for To-do items and has been using these for many months. Suddenly the custom views vanished.

Any ideas?